# iOS app allows scroll above application boundaries

Tags: ios, css, iphone, cordova, visual-studio-cordova

I am creating an iOS app from a Visual Studio Apache Cordova project and i have built the design and functionality to work fine but i am running into one problem i can't quite figure out because i don't know how to word it properly.

On every screen in my app, i have an image set to 100% 100% that acts as a background to the app and it works fine in simulators and on the android app but when I deploy it on an apple device the iOS environment allows scroll on screens that have no need for it and messes with some of the functionality of the app.

The screen is supposed to stay locked in this state

[image]

but instead allows scrolling past the boundaries of the app view like this

[image]
[image]

How can i fix this app to make the screen stay locked in place with no scrolling abilities outside of the image view?

Comment: Please show html + css layout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

adding

```
<preference name="DisallowOverscroll" value="true" />
```

to the config.xml file fixed this issue